# Excel UDF - VLOOKUP with partial match and concatenate results in single cell

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have 2 column data and a third column of query terms. The query terms have a partial but exact match in column1 of data ("Data1"). I want to find all matches for the query term in "Data1" column and return comma separated values from "Data2" column.

Please see the image.

There is already a UDF for similar problem on this site but that doesnt quite do what i want.

[Excel: Return multiple matches in a single cell while doing a partial match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901262/excel-return-multiple-matches-in-a-single-cell-while-doing-a-partial-match/55372713#55372713)

Thank you so much for your help. Best Wishes Manoj[Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTKsx.png)

I have tried this UDF:

```
Public Function ConcatPartLookUp(rngInput As Range, rngSource As Range, Optional strDelimiter As String, Optional blCaseSensitive)
Dim rng As Range

If strDelimiter = "" Then strDelimiter = "|"
If IsMissing(blCaseSensitive) Then
    blCaseSensitive = False
Else
    blCaseSensitive = True
End If

For Each rng In rngSource
    If blCaseSensitive Then
        If InStr(1, rng.Value, rngInput.Value, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then ConcatPartLookUp = ConcatPartLookUp & strDelimiter & rng.Value
    Else
        If InStr(1, rng.Value, rngInput.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ConcatPartLookUp = ConcatPartLookUp & strDelimiter & rng.Value
    End If
Next

If Len(ConcatPartLookUp) > 0 Then ConcatPartLookUp = Mid(ConcatPartLookUp, 2, Len(ConcatPartLookUp))

End Function
```

This code will return matches from "Data1" column (Very blue sky.|Blue sky forever.). I am looking to match on Data1 but return values from Data2.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Post your code here so that we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Office 365 Excel then you can use TEXTJOIN as an Array Formula:

```
 =TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,$A$2:$A$6)),$B$2:$B$6,""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

---

If you do not have Office 365 then put this code in a Module and then use the formula as described above:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Scott. Thanks for the TEXTJOIN UDF. I tried it now. Unfortunately, it returns values from Data1 column. However, i am looking to match on Data1 but return values from Data2. For, example, your formula returns - "Very blue sky.,Blue sky forever." whereas the answer i want is "Sky1,Sky3"